# Extract inner element without looping

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

Extracting the href value from the following sample HTML code is straight forward if I loop through all  and break immediately after the first one:

```
  <li class="parts partname parts_first">
    <div id="dpdn10" uri="/public/page/part1" class="partype partstate">
      <div class="ptctainer">
        <div class="ptitle">
          <p class="ptypead">
            <span class="rtext"><a href="http://www.example.com/page/ptname.html?dv=rfirst" class="mnLabel">First</a></span>
            <span class="ndx">
              <a href="#" dndx="dpdn10" class="xpnd _t" style="opacity:1">Details: </a>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="dpdn10_content" class="xpns">
        <div class="ptctainer">
          <div class="ptitle">
            <p class="ptypead">
              <span class="rtext"><a href="http://www.example.com/page/ptname.html?dv=rfirst" class="mnLabel">First</a></span>
              <span class="ndx"><a href="#" class="xpnd">Details: </a></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

I can certainly do that when I can assume the href value is identical for both instances of  as in the example above.

However, this approach fails if they are not identical and I want to extract a specific one (either the first or the second).

Which brings me to searching for a mechanism in Jsoup that allows "nested selection": Up until now I have been familiar with single-level selection as in:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");  // img with src ending .png
Element masthead = doc.select("div.masthead").first();  // div with class=masthead
```

But I can't find documentation or an example for multi-level selection, e.g.

```
Element link= doc.select("div.xpns.div.ptctainer.div.ptitle.p.ptypead.span.rtext");
```

The above is for illustration and not real syntax, of course. I don't know if something like this is possible (yet) in Jsoup.

Does such "nested selection" exist in Jsoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just 'chain' the selection functions? Like:

```
Element link = doc.select("div.xpns").select("div.ptctainer").select("div.ptitle").select("p.ptypead").select("span.rtext");
```

Comment: Of course I can but the "chained" form implies less optimized traversal/parsing. I was hoping for perhaps Jsoup handles such scenario in an optimized manner. Thanks and +1.

Comment: Parsing is always slow. Ideally you'd skip it all together.

Comment: I had hoped Jsoup would have multi-level mechanism similar to the [ancestor child](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) it already has. But it seems that this isn't available yet.

Answer (score 4):

The jsoup selectors work just like CSS. See the [Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) document for the full support.

You can do descendent selections like this:

```
Element link = doc.select("div.xpns div.ptctainer div.ptitle p.ptypead span.rtext").first();
```

If the tag name is not important to the selection, and you only need to use the class name:

```
Element link = doc.select(".xpns .ptctainer .ptitle .ptypead .rtext").first();
```

These queries are very effiecient.