# Descendant selectors in a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I can very well understand from this [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_descendant.htm) what element/tag based *descendant selectors* are, how and why they work and for what purpose.

But then I came across certain websites which define a class name for an anchor `<a>` which is made of several names separated by spaces, e.g.

```
<a class="samename nav_item samename" href="/messages/?refid=7"> Text </a>
```

I then found out that these are also called "[descendant selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771462/extract-inner-element-without-looping/5827644#5827644)" -- or are they called [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#combinators)?

This is where I stopped understanding:

1. Is the 2nd type of "descendant
   selectors" the same as the 1st type?
2. Does the 2nd type of "descendant
   selectors" have a [different name](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors),
   that can help me differentiate it
   from the 1st type when referring to
   it?
3. What is the purpose of this 2nd type
   of "descendant selectors"?
4. Why repeat `samename` in such
   descendant selector?

Any tips or pointers to places where I can learn more about this 2nd type would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** The replies below helped put order into things, especially in regard to proper terminology. I will try to summarize my understanding so far -- first by attempting to answer the questions above in a respective manner, then listing some insights, with the hope that it can help future css-laymen like me:

1. The 2nd type is not "descendant
   selectors" at all, so it cannot
   possibly be the same as the 1st
   type.
2. The name for the 2nd type, for now,
   is `multiple class names assigned to the same tag`.
3. One use of attributing multiple classes per element is that one can then chain class selectors, such that only elements with all the classes listed are matched, not those that have one or fewer of the classes.
4. This is most likely a programming mistake/error/bug (although I found it on a very prominent website).

Insights (please correct if you spot a mistake):

1. Despite what's written in
   [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp), a class (name) is
   **not** a selector! A selector can only be an HTML element.
2. However, a CSS [rule](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/rule.htm) may refer
   to an HTML element (or a group of
   HTML elements) by class name, using
   the `.classname` notation. This
   notation is referred to by some as
   "[the class selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)" and this
   is where my confusion stemmed from. It merely means it can be used to select any HTML element that has a class **attribute**.
3. A CSS rule may also refer to an HTML
   element (or a group of HTML
   elements) by element id, using the
   `#elementid` notation. This is an
   entirely different subject but since
   this notation is referred to by some
   as "[the id selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)" it's quite
   possible this could be a source for
   confusion as well, so it's briefly
   mentioned here.
4. In HTML, "class" is an attribute. In
   CSS, it is a "[selector aggregator](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm)",
   used to select any HTML element that
   has that class attribute.
5. The best CSS *tutorial*, by far, is
   [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm#combining).

Comment: Um, those aren't called "descendant selectors" to my knowledge...

Comment: Regarding your edit, attribute selectors (which I see you made a link to) are entirely different from descendant combinators.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks a million and many more ++ for correcting the terminology. I just learned from you that these are called `descendant combinators`, not "descendant selectors". Also, can you recommend a better source for learning CSS which *isn't* the formal specification? I get a headache just from looking at the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#tokenization)...

Comment: Most of my CSS learning comes from reading miscellaneous articles around the Web and tons of practice :)

Comment: Just to clarify your point #3 - In the CSS, you can refer to any of the following (and use several of them to be more specific): HTML elements (such as p, a, etc) with no extra notation, classes (preceded by a period), and IDs (preceded by a hash mark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one CSS descendant selector, and that is the space character:

```
E F /* Selects any F that descends from (or is contained by) an E */
```

Space-separated class names are just multiple classes that are separated by spaces, in a single HTML `class` attribute. The `class` attribute is not a selector, in fact not even part of CSS for that matter.

On a somewhat related note, however, one use of listing multiple classes per element is that you can then chain class selectors, such that only elements with *all* the classes listed are matched, not those that have one or fewer of the classes. For example:

```
.samename.nav_item /* Selects only elements that have both classes */
```

As to why `samename` is repeated in your given HTML, I have no idea. It's the same as having just one `samename` class.

Comment: Obligatory "IE6 doesn't interpret multiple class selectors properly" warning goes here.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the clarifications so far. I understand that the `class` attribute is not a selector, but in [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771462/extract-inner-element-without-looping/5827644#5827644) it is used a selector. Also in your own reply you are referring to "chain class selectors". Can you clarify this? Thanks and +2.

Comment: @BoltClock Also in [this CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) the `class` attribute is definitely referred to as selector. I am now *really* confused...

Comment: @ef2011: The selector in that SO answer refers to the use of a CSS selector in a JavaScript library function, which is different from the `class` attribute. In that post, each class name is prefixed with a dot and separated by a space. That means the space *is* used as a descendant selector, but again that's CSS selector syntax, not the HTML attribute. Hopefully you're clearer about the difference now!

Comment: @ef2011: That's W3Schools for you. Close the tab, remove it from your browser history and forget it. It's an unofficial source, and one that's shoddily-written at that. Those are called attributes, not selectors, *period.*

Comment: @BoltClock +2 again. This information is invaluable for me. How about [tizag](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/selector.php)?

Comment: Actually, I was on what seems the best CSS tutorial so far: [Selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/rule.htm).

Comment: Errr, in case anyone else stumbles upon my comments, I realized jsoup is a Java HTML parser, not JavaScript. Oops!

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the a tag actually has several different classes (of which one is listed twice, for some reason).

In CSS code, we'd use a space to separate decendant selectors, but in HTML it just lets us put several classes in the same set of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks and +1. See my comments to @BoltClock.