# CSS selector to find all <h2> elements that are descendants of elements with classname="classname"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

What would be a CSS Selector equivalent of `xpath= "//*[@class='classname']//descendant::h2"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Descendant selectors in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131196/descendant-selectors-in-a-class)

Comment: @BoltClock CSS selectors have nothing to do with Java - this is a CSS question so should be tagged CSS, not Java. Even if he's using it in Selenium.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475553/css-selector-for-class-descendant-within-a-class which is a slightly different question, but whose answer should make it obvious what the answer to your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
.classname h2 {

}
```

OR

```
[class='classname'] h2 {

}
```

Comment: Dont know why down vote! whats wrong with this answer?