# Can't get image src in html using jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get the instagram img of the post using jsoup with this query but not getting any result.Please help!

the img tag which i want to scrap from this post has id=pImage_0

```
 doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.instagram.com/p/BQGyI2JjKUN/").get();
        title = doc.title();  
        System.out.println("Title:"+title);
        Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
        for (Element image : images) {
            System.out.println("src : " + image.attr("src"));
            System.out.println("height : " + image.attr("height"));
            System.out.println("width : " + image.attr("width"));
            System.out.println("alt : " + image.attr("alt"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That webpage `https://www.instagram.com/p/BQGyI2JjKUN/` is Javascript rendered so when you make an http request and attempt to scrape the site all you get back is javascript, which is why you see nothing when you try to `sysout` the `image.attr`'s since it finds nothing. If you view the `view-source:https://www.instagram.com/p/BQGyI2JjKUN/`, that's all you have to scrape. The only way you're scraping these images is by faking a web browsing session by creating a bot or using [instagram's API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints).

You could google `java headless browser` and find some stuff that could help. Here are some useful ones that could accomplish that too

- [Jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/)
- [Ghost](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

That website uses AJAX calls to load their data.

and simple request won't execute JS at all.

You have 2 options.

1) inspect all AJAX calls/URLs and their parameters and send request to those URLs
2) Or use Selenium or PhantomJS.

Comment: I have to do that in android so i will be using java. Is there any other lib available for this purpose in java?

Comment: Search for Selenium Java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771462/extract-inner-element-without-looping   can i get the data by chaining?

Comment: Not sure but use Instagram API thats the best for you